# What is the ruby equivalent of the python BeautifulSoup library?

Tags: python, ruby, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for a forgiving HTML parser for scraping HTML and extracting data in Ruby. I've had success using BeautifulSoup for this - what is the ruby equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)

Also see:
[Nokogiri vs Hpricot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888587/nokogiri-vs-hpricot) before making a choice.
Nokogiri seems to outdo hpricot performance-wise (haven't benchmarked myself) and has a nice syntax IMO.

Comment: Thank you. I used Nokogiri and it was sufficient for my purposes. I think the HTML I through at it was well-formed, so I have researched how fault tolerant it is.

Comment: Update for 2013: the Hpricot readme on github says it is no longer maintained and recommends Nokogiri instead.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [Rubyful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/RubyfulSoup/) gem, which was a Ruby port of BeautifulSoup, but it's no longer maintained and their site now recommends [hpricot](http://github.com/whymirror/hpricot).